# Ошибка Django-phone-login

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Я использую [Django-phone-login](https://github.com/wejhink/django-phone-login) для регистрации авторизации с помощью номер телефона . Я установил и сделал settings.py как показана на github е . Но при миграции выдает такое ошибка

> : (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[0]' refers to 'phone_number', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'PhoneTokenAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'phone_login.PhoneToken'.

Если кто то знает причину помогите пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Это похвально, что вы сделали "settings.py как показана на github е ". Но судя по приведенной ошибке проблема не в настройках. Проблема где-то в коде, который оперирует объектами list_display и phone_number. Что-то подробнее сказать не получится. Нужен код или хотя бы полный вывод ошибки.

Comment: вес код вот здесь https://github.com/wejhink/django-phone-login